# phpmailer user attachment not attaching/working

Tags: php, phpmailer

first of all i know there are many answers related to my question but not actually what i want.. so thats why i post here..

here is my html form snippit

```
<form action="include/jobs.php" id="jobform" name="jobform" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <div class="form-process"></div>

                            <div class="col_half">
                                <label for="jobform-fname">First Name <small>*</small></label>
                                <input type="text" id="jobform-fname" name="jobform-fname" value="" class="form-control required" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col_half col_last">
                                <label for="jobform-lname">Last Name <small>*</small></label>
                                <input type="text" id="jobform-lname" name="jobform-lname" value="" class="form-control required" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="col_half">
                                <label for="jobform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                <input type="email" id="jobform-email" name="jobform-email" value="" class="required email form-control" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col_half col_last">
                                <label for="contactform-phone">Phone <small>*</small></label>
                                <input type="text" id="contactform-phone" name="contactform-phone" value="" class="form-control required" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="col_full">
                                <label for="jobform-service">Position <small>*</small></label>
                                <select name="jobform-position" id="jobform-position"  tabindex="9" class="form-control required">
                                    <option value="">-- Select Position --</option>
                                    <option value="Business Executive">Business Executive</option>
                                    <option value="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</option>
                                    <option value="Event Manager">Event Manager</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="col_full">
                                <label for="jobform-cvfile">Upload CV <small>*</small></label>
                                <input type="file" id="jobform-cvfile" name="jobform-cvfile[]" value="" multiple class="required form-control file-loading"/>
                                <div id="errorBlock" class="help-block"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="col_full">
                                <label for="contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
                                <textarea class="required form-control" id="contactform-message" name="contactform-message" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col_full hidden">
                                <input type="text" id="jobform-botcheck" name="jobform-botcheck" value="" class="form-control" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col_full">

                                <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeCeiYTAAAAACYHIfo4cPO1RoeJkSs_awiB_vVh"></div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col_full">
                                <button class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-dirtygreen tright" name="jobform-apply" type="submit" value="apply"><i class="icon-line-arrow-right"></i><span>Send Application</span></button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

and here is phpmailer script

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
            'email' => 'email@email.com',
            'name' => 'company name'
        );

$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Application and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

$recaptcha_secret = 'key'; // Your reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

$fname = $_POST['jobform-fname'];
$lname = $_POST['jobform-lname'];
$email = $_POST['jobform-email'];
$position = $_POST['jobform-position'];
$phone = $_POST['contactform-phone'];
$message = $_POST['contactform-message'];

$name = $fname . ' ' . $lname;

$subject = 'New Job Application';

$botcheck = $_POST['jobform-botcheck'];

if( $botcheck == '' ) {

    $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
    $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
    foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
        $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
    }
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
    $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
    $phone = isset($phone) ? "Telephone: $age<br><br>" : '';
    $position = isset($position) ? "Position: $position<br><br>" : '';
    $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

    $body = "$name $email $phone $position $message $referrer";

    if ( isset( $_FILES['jobform-cvfile'] ) && $_FILES['jobform-cvfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['jobform-cvfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['jobform-cvfile']['name'] );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
        $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

        $g_response = json_decode( $response );

        if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
            die;
        }
    }

    $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
    $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

    if( $sendEmail == true ):
        echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
    else:
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
    endif;
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
}
} else {
echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

so all fields are working fine.. i can recive details of all fields in my mail except, the attachment is not coming to me..

so my question is what is the problem? im not that into php.. i know few things, if the answers are detailed it will be great.. thank you...

and one more optional question is that is there a way to specify file size limit in phpmailer?

Comment: You have to do some basic debugging and isolate the part of the code that isn't working. It's a bit crazy that you're trying to receive by email a file that you don't even know whether it's getting uploaded in the first place.

Comment: And apart from debugging, just add sanity checks in the code as well. An upload may fail. Have you checked [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?